# 'pathmunge' function for arbitrary 'PATH'-like variables

Tags: bash

I'm sure many of you are familiar with the canonical `pathmunge` function used in Bourne-shell-compatible dotfiles to prevent duplicate entries in the `PATH` variable. I have also created similar functions for the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `MANPATH` variables, so I have the following three functions in my `.bashrc`:

```
# function to avoid adding duplicate entries to the PATH
pathmunge () {
    case ":${PATH}:" in
        *:"$1":*)
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                PATH=$PATH:$1
            else
                PATH=$1:$PATH
            fi
    esac
}

# function to avoid adding duplicate entries to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ldpathmunge () {
    case ":${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:" in
        *:"$1":*)
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$1
            else
                LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$1:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
            fi
    esac
}

# function to avoid adding duplicate entries to the MANPATH
manpathmunge () {
    case ":${MANPATH}:" in
        *:"$1":*)
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                MANPATH=$MANPATH:$1
            else
                MANPATH=$1:$MANPATH
            fi
    esac
}
```

Are there any elegant ways that I can combine these three functions into one to keep my `.bashrc` file smaller? Maybe a way that I can pass in which variable to check/set, similar to passing-by-reference in C?

Comment: You can use `eval` with the name of the variable that you're trying to manipulate.

Comment: If you'd like to write that out in an answer for credit, feel free. Otherwise, I just crafted up a solution with that and it works, and I'll post it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `eval` to get and set the value of a variable knowing its name; the following function works both in Bash and in [Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell):

```
varmunge ()
{
  : '
  Invocation: varmunge <varname> <dirpath> [after]
  Function:   Adds <dirpath> to the list of directories in <varname>. If  <dirpath> is
              already present in <varname> then <varname> is left unchanged. If the third
               argument is "after" then <dirpath> is added to the end of <varname>, otherwise
               it is added at the beginning.
  Returns:    0 if everthing was all right, 1 if something went wrong.
  ' :
  local pathlist
  eval "pathlist=\"\$$1\"" 2>/dev/null || return 1
  case ":$pathlist:" in
    *:"$2":*)
      ;;
    "::")
      eval "$1=\"$2\"" 2>/dev/null || return 1
      ;;
    *)
      if [ "$3" = "after" ]; then
        eval "$1=\"$pathlist:$2\"" 2>/dev/null || return 1
      else
        eval "$1=\"$2:$pathlist\"" 2>/dev/null || return 1
      fi
      ;;
  esac
  return 0
}
```

Comment: You can more safely use `declare` in place of `eval`.

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate? What's the syntax, and why is it safer?

Comment: It's safer because it doesn't actually try to execute any code; it *only* processes assignments. `declare "$1=$pathlist:$2"`.

Comment: @chepner: `declare` does not work in Dash. For Bash only see the excellent answer by user dpw.

Comment: @AlexP For a question tagged `bash`, what `dash` does or doesn't support isn't really relevant.

Comment: @chepner: The question asks about Bourne-compatible shells. The answer explicitly says that this function works in both Bash and Dash. Moreover, there is an excellent Bash-only answer in this thread. Other than that you are right of course that if `declare` is available then it is safer.

Answer (score 4):

In Bash 4.3 or later, you can use `declare -n` to effectively pass a variable by reference.

```
# function to avoid adding duplicate entries to the PATH
pathmunge () {
    declare -n thepath=$1
    case ":${thepath}:" in
        *:"$2":*)
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "$3" = "after" ] ; then
                thepath=$thepath:$2
            else
                thepath=$2:$thepath
            fi
            ;;
    esac
}
```

You'd call it something like this:

`pathmunge PATH ~/bin`

`pathmunge MANPATH /usr/local/man after`

Comment: I'm not doubting your solution, but I don't have the `-n` option on my system in GNU bash 4.1.2, so this solution doesn't work for me

Comment: Ah, bummer.  I hadn't realized that `declare -n` was introduced as late as bash 4.3.